$\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(X,x_0)]$-module structure on $\pi_n(X,x_0)$.
I'm fairly new to algebraic topology and I have found myself trying to solve the following Problem:

Let $(X,x_0)$ be a based space and $n\geq0$. Show that $\pi_n(X,x_0)$ admits a unique $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(X,x_0)]$ structure such that $[\gamma]\cdot f = \gamma_*(f)$ for every $\gamma:([0,1],\{0,1\}) \rightarrow (X,x_0)$ and $f \in \pi_n(X,x_0)$. Where $\gamma_*$ denotes the group homomorphism $\pi_n(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_n(X,x_0)$.

My main issue is that I don't undestand what that "group homomorphism $\gamma_*$" is. I see $\gamma$ as a loop based at $x_0$ (so we essentially look at $\pi_1(X,x_0)$) and $\gamma$ acts on $\pi_n(X,x_0)$. My research so far has lead me to believe that we are "moving $f$ along $\gamma$" but here again, I struggle to understand what that means. How is such a movement defined? (how should I approach understanding the way in which it affects the class of $f$?)

Do you know the standard proof that homotopy groups are independent of the base-point?

I don't know it (only briefly read it).

Then you should read it in detail.

Could you recommend a ressource? (I'm afraid my notes lack clarity).

Any textbook on algebraic topology, say, Hatcher's book, which is freely available.

I might be misunderstanding: In Hatcher's book, I found a proof in the context of $\pi_1(X)$ (Prop 1.5 and the paragraph leading to it) which I was familiar with. I didn't find the proof for the more general statement in the book, but my undestanding of it is that it is similar in nature.

Related (as in, it quotes Hatcher's description of a loop acting on a class in $\pi_n$): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2115480/42781

Did you check page 341 and, more generally, section 4.A of Hatcher's book?
